# .net framework 4.7.2 broke httpclient

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api2

My ASP.NET MVC project used HttpClient.PostAsync() to post to a webAPI endpoint.  All is fine until I recently upgraded the project to target .NET Framework 4.7.2. Now the call will end with HTTP Status 405 (Method not allowed). However, endpoints with [HTTPGet] work. In a desperate measure, I set the API controller with  [EnableCors(origins: "*", headers: "*", methods: "*")] and call the endpoint with the same domain and port (localhost to localhost).  I even reverted the project to 4.6.1. It still throws 405 error. Could you help?  Thank you.

```js
public static async Task < T > Post < T > (string baseUrl, string urlSegment, HttpContent postContent) {
  string responseContent = string.Empty;
  Uri returnUrl = null;

  using(HttpClient client = GetClient(baseUrl)) {
    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync(urlSegment.TrimStart('/'), postContent).ConfigureAwait(false);
    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode) {
      returnUrl = response.Headers.Location;
    }
    return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject < T > (returnUrl.ToString());
  }
}
```

Comment: So if you revert to 4.6.1 and get the same issue, why do you think 4.7.2 is to blame?

Comment: I also restored the compiled file sets from a backup that targeted 4.6.1 and it worked.  There is nothing else changed.

Comment: 405 is a response sent by the server, so there's something different in the request. You can capture and compare your requests using a tool like Fiddler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that the WebAPI endpoint path has been changed.  In addition, I reverted the GIT commit to rollback to a version before I upgrade to DotNet Framework 4.7.2, then cherry-picked all the commits after the 4.7.2 upgrade.